# Sublime text 2 how to delete comments only

Tags: sublimetext2

In my sass code, I have inline comments and I wish to remove these in sublime text. Is it possible to permanently delete all comment content alone?

```
@function emCalc($values) {
  $emValues: '';
  $max: length($values); //Get the total number of parameters passed
  @for $i from 1 through $max {
    $value: (nth($values, $i)); //Take the individual parameter
    $value: $value / ($value * 0 + 1); //Doing this gets you one unit (1px)
    $value: $value / $em-base * 1em; //Divide the px value by emBase and return the value as em
    $emValues: #{$emValues + $value}; //Append to array
    @if $i < $max {
      $emValues: #{$emValues + " "}; //Adding space between parameters (except last), if there are multiple parameters
    }
  }
  @return $emValues; //Call emCalc like so emCalc(10, 20, 30, 40) it should return margin: 0.625em 1.25em 1.875em 2.5em
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you have no other possibility, you could select every `//` (Select first `//` then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> while there's comments left if my memory is correct).

Then press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>End</kbd> to select every end of line with a `//` and <kbd>Del</kbd> ! :)

(There's probably a plugin for that, but this is the simplest method I think. This suggest that all your `//` refers to the beginning of a comment, of course)

Comment: Ctrl + D worked great but I had to keep doing it for as many number of comments that were there. ctrl+f and alt+enter got me there in 2 steps compared to pressing ctrl+D several times 

Thanks for the wonderful tip, it worked great!

Comment: Best Trick i have ever seens. thanks. it will help me to make my code neat and clean

Answer (score 39):

You'll need to double check this (have a backup handy!), but the following regular expression should work in the "replace" window, with regular expressions enabled (the * icon):

1. Open the "replace" window (ctrl + h / cmd + option + f)
2. Enable regular expression matching by making sure the `*` icon is selected
3. Enter the following in the "Find What?" box

   ```
   \/\/.*
   ```
4. Leave the "replace with" box empty to delete found text.
5. Click "Replace All"

### Edit

as @ollie noted, this also will delete any urls prefixed with `//`. The following (lightly tested) regex should serve to better target comments: `(^\/\/.*)|(\s+\/\/.*)`

### Edit v2

A solution for single and multi-line comments `(^\/\/.*)|(\s+\/\/.*)|((\/\*)(.|\n)+?(\*\/))`

Comment: This is a great approach. Is there a way to modify it for HTML comments? Harder as these may be on 2 lines, e.g. `<!-- Code //new line// more code -->`

Comment: @Ollie you are absolutely right, i've updated with what is hopefully a  better regex solution. Improvements very much welcomed.

Comment: This is pretty great, but doesn't take into account multi-line comments (/* something */).

Comment: @Crates  updated with a multiline solution (I just saw your own answer which I will +1)

Comment: This is boss. Perfect

Answer (score 9):

None of the answers here seem to take advantage of the fact that the syntax highlighting has already determined where all the comments are - just execute this in the Python console (View menu -> Show Console) to select all comments:

```
view.sel().clear(); view.sel().add_all(view.find_by_selector('comment'))
```

(press <kbd>Enter</kbd> after typing/pasting it to execute it)
then press <kbd>Delete</kbd> to delete all the selections and <kbd>Esc</kbd> to go back to single selection mode

Comment: This works perfectly and since it utilizes the in-built syntax highlighting of Sublime text, so you don't have to worry about missing any of the comments or deleting something that's not a comment by accident. I tested this in a html document to delete all javascript comments and it worked correctly. Will this also work for HTML comments and C++ comments?

Comment: yes it will with any syntax definition that correctly scopes comments, so definitely any that come bundled with ST qualify, probably all of them do really :)

Comment: works as advertised, unfortunately highlight+delete ruins the space formatting and in many areas the code for lua and others and u'll have to go in and manually fix.

Answer (score 6):

None of the other answers cover all cases (multi-line comments, single line comments, double-slash comments and slash-star/star-slash comments).

In order to match all possible cases (without matching URLs), use the following:

```
(^[\s]*?\/\/.*)|(/\*[\s\S]+?\*/)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I do in ST3 in HTML to strip all comments, especially nasty comments embedded within `<p>` body text, for example ...

1. package control install `SelectUntil`
2. quit and restart sublime
3. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+f `<!--`
4. <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> to select all instances of `<!--`
5. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+s will pull up an input field, where
   you can type: `-->`
6. hit delete!

Comment: The question is not about HTML, though.

Comment: Thank you for `SelectUntil` plugin.

Comment: Alt + Shift + S on Windows.

Comment: nhahtdh is right. But I came here searching for what Rowe say. So, thanks for it!

Comment: Great answer. Will apply for all programming languages

Answer (score 0):

Well well, there is an easy way to do it in mac Sublime Text if you are sure there are no // in print statements.

search for `//` and hit that `cmd+ctrl+G` and then to select the whole line which has hit `cmd+shift+Arrow` and delete it. Assuming you have used only single line comments