# Is there a way to delete all comment lines in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, comments, sublimetext3

I know in Vim you can delete all comments in a file with a keyboard shortcut, but I have been unsuccessful finding a similar technique in ST3. This would be particularly useful for gemfiles and other files that have distracting comments everywhere.

Looking for a keyboard shortcut or a quick and easy alternative.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sublime text 2 how to delete comments only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364130/sublime-text-2-how-to-delete-comments-only)

Comment: BTW how to delete all comments in a file with a keyboard shortcut in vim?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simplest is to use a regex search-and-replace, e.g.,

- <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Opt</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd>
- Select the <kbd>.*</kbd> option (regex)
- Find What: `^#.*\n` <sup>Note 1</sup>
- Replace With: (nothing)

This won't work for comment blocks. For them you need to be a bit trickier, (very) roughly:

```
=begin(.|\n)*=end
```

<sup>*(Not tested robustly.)*</sup>

If you do this a lot (which IMO is a little strange) you could bind it to a key.

---

<sup>Note 1: This works for comments at the beginning of lines. It doesn't do comments appended to code lines; if you want to handle that then you can remove the `^` but you'll need to so something about the EOLs that would disappear during replacement. Or you can just ignore the EOL and have some blank lines where line comments were.</sup>

Answer (score 8):

What Dave answered didn't work for me. So do the following if its the same case for you too,

To delete *all* specific <tag> element including contents inside it:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> (on PC)
- Enable (Regular Expression):  <kbd>.*</kbd>  icon or  <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
- Find What:

  RE syntax to work with a particular tag,

  > **(?s)<start tag>.*?<end tag>**

  Such as, for CSS comment tags,

  > **(?s)/*.*?*/**

  For HTML comment tags,

  > **(?s)<!--.*?-->**
- Replace With: Leave the field blank
- <kbd>Replace All</kbd>

Comment: For block comments, the following worked for me using RegReplace and find and replace:
`\/\*([\s\S]*?)\*\/`

Comment: The HTML comment tags expression works, I've found that the CSS comment tags expression instead returns an error message: Invalid preceding regular expression prior to repetition operator.