# Javascript RegExp: How to remove all charcters after // until a new line

Tags: javascript, regex

Basically what I want to do is parse code, and remove all comments made with "//", including the "//", until a new line appears. I don't know how to effectivly do it in Regex unfortunately.

Some example code might look like this:

```
variable += 10; //comment to be removed.
more code...
```

so only "//comment to be removed." gets removed

Comment: What have you tried till now?

Comment: You don't need regex but can use: `.replace(/\/\/.*/, '')`

Comment: Do you have Sublime Text? Check this out - [linkie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364130/sublime-text-2-how-to-delete-comments-only)

Answer (score 2):

```js
console.log(`something // awodkajwodkjoawjdojawdjk
another thing // fgskgkjhgkf
last thing`.replace(/\/\/.*/g, ''));
```

Comment: @pillikasnazsaxc you are welcome. Please feel free to upvote and [accept](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png) the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This will allow you to parse the code, instead of just removing the comments from a string:

```
var code = getCode();
var stripped = '';
var regex = /(.*)\/\/.*/g;
var result;
while ( result = regex.exec( code ) ) {
    console.log( result );
    // Do other stuff with line of code
    stripped += ( result[1] + '\n' );
}
```